# Angular JS application taking around 100% CPU while resizing

Tags: angularjs, window-resize

My website is in AngularJS v1.7.2 (using Laravel PHP framework as backend).
Current issue is the website freezes after resizing several times (2-3 or more times). I have checked Google chrome Task Manager Tool and it showing around 100% of CPU usage at the time of freezes. Same issue also occurred while testing the site in mobile by changing orientation several times. I have already tried solution like bind one way, add track by for ng-repeat, using tools like Batarang but no luck yet. Is there any proper solution for the issue. Please let me know.

**UPDATE**
The website almost finish. Only the freeze issue currently blocking us. The website mainly containing song, album, playlist, artist. 
On home page there is banner (4 images) using [iosSlider](https://www.iosscripts.com/iosslider/) . then there are per category (8 categories) album (5 album each). on right sidebar there are song list. There are other pages like category page, artist page, album page, song page, user profile pages etc. Also there is a customised player using [angular soundmanager2](https://github.com/perminder-klair/angular-soundmanager2) API. Generally while viewing in desktop normally there no issue so far. But if I check using Device Toolbar (`CTRL`+`Shift`+`M`) and switch to other pages and rotate 2-3 times it just freezes. Even can't reload or refresh the page tab. If I check Chrome Task manager (`Shift`+`Esc`) it shows around 100% CPU usages
that time. Thing to notice the issue only occurring if I route to other page(forward or backward or both) then rotate 2-3 times. I am using AngularJS Batarang to sort out the issue but with no clue still now

**SOLVED**
The issue was with [iosSlider](https://www.iosscripts.com/iosslider/). After removing the iosSlider no crash issue now.

Comment: do you run any code with a `resize` event?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please share some more details about your website, as it's impossible to exactly tell what the problem is based in your description. Did you try debugging in the dev tools, like checking what exactly is taking up the resources or just pause javascript?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey currently no code using  `resize`  event

Comment: I would suggest to check to Performance tab in your browser. Also try to check for any issues with watchers. Maybe you are creating too many of them somehow. You can run [this code](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef) to check them from a console. Remove `.length` to see their details

Comment: @Capricorn data updated. Please check and let me know if there any solution for the issue